# Downloading with wget

Tags: wget

When I download anything by means of wget, how can I set the download directory? I mean just like while normally downloading something from web there's a prompt asking where to save. Is it possible to set the directory while downloading with wget?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -P option to download contents to a diiferent directory(no need to use cd).syntax:

```
wget -P <directory where you want to save> <url of the file>
```

eg:

```
wget -P /home/basil/Desktop http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/treetog/junior/256/document-excel-icon.png
```

Comment: So is it wget -P /directory #link , like that?

Comment: Yes the command in the example provided will download 'document-excel-icon.png' to my desktop

Answer (score 2):

When you open the terminal, by default, you are in your home directory. If you wish to download with `wget` into some other directory, simply change directories to the desired location; for example:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://blah/some_file
```

Or, another example:

```
cd ~/Desktop
wget http://blah/some_file
```